# What is the total prevalence percentage for pre-diabetics and diabetics for black race in the US?

Tags: metabolism, pre-diabetes, ethnicity, race, type-2-diabetes

What is the total prevalence percentage for pre-diabetics and diabetics for black race in the US?

I had a black friend who worry about this, i want to comfort him by saying that this number is not high, don't worry.

Comment: http://www.diabetes.org/diabetes-basics/statistics/